# I am having a problem modifying some of my property values for an svg component in React project

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

The pointer property works, however, the fill property doesn't work. When I open the console on the browser and see the elements I can change the element.style which will affect the styling for the svg component.

I have tried changing the element.style and I used the !important next to the fill property and it still didn't work

```
//React file

//This is the import
import { ReactComponent as Dot } from './dot.svg';

//code itself
<div className="home">
  <Dot className="dotSvg"/>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</div>

//css file and outside wrapper
.container{
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    /* grid-template-rows: 100px 300px; */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.dotSvg{ 
cursor: pointer; 
fill: #5AE2EB; 
}


///the inside of the dot.svg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 2 2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;"><circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" style="fill-opacity:0;"/></svg>
```

I would like to be able to fill the svg component using the fill property

Comment: What's in dot.svg?

Comment: Robert Longson I'll add it in right now

Comment: the circle has fill-opacity:0 which means any fill is transparent.

Comment: should I remove that property?

Comment: You can remove `fill-opacity` or do this `fill-opacity:1`.

Comment: I removed it and it worked thanks for the tip everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is happening because of the `style="fill-opacity:0;"` on the `<circle>` element. Removing this or increasing the opacity should allow the fill to be visible